# After Meteor 0.9 new package system, How do you update meteor packages?

Tags: meteor

I ran meteor update to upgrade my app from 0.9.0 to 0.9.1.1 and after the update it got stuck on 'Figuring out the best packages to use...' for a long time so I had to ctrl-c to quit. My app still works fine though but I am worried that all the packages might not be at the latest versions.

With meteorite you would use mrt update to update all the packages. With the new meteor package system, do you just run meteor update and it will automatically update the packages for you?

I noticed that in the packages file, many of the packages have a version specified along with it, do you have to manually manage the version or will meteor upgrade the versions for you?

Answer (score 0):

It should update all I think but for now there are some problems with this :/

Try: `meteor update author:package-name`

or you can remove and add it: `meteor remove author:package-name` and then `meteor add author:package-name`

Comment: ah so i have to do this for each package individually? But what if I want to run a command to check all packages and upgrade them if necessary? When you say 'it should update all' do you mean that in the future Meteor will automatically upgrade the packages, just right now it doesn't because of bugs?

Comment: I think yes.. we will see how meteor tool will work in v0.9.2